# Default value for a field, based on another field's value

Tags: django, functional-programming

How can I define the `default` for a Django model field, to be based on the value of another field on the same instance?

I want to define a `code` for the model based on the `created` timestamp:

```python
from django.db import models

class LoremIpsum(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        default=(
            lambda x: "LOREM-{0.created:%Y%m%d-%H%M%S}".format(x)),
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )
```

That doesn't work because the function defined for `default` receives no argument.

How can I define a default for the `code` field such that it is derived from that instance's `created` field value?

Comment: My advice would be to set the value after you create the object initially. You cannot set a default value based on something that doesn't exist. If you do it after the creation, you'll be able to utilize your `created` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/signals/), this can be done by defining a function to **receive [the `post_init` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/signals/#post-init) from the model**.

```python
from django.db import models
import django.dispatch

class LoremIpsum(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
    )

@django.dispatch.receiver(models.signals.post_init, sender=LoremIpsum)
def set_default_loremipsum_code(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Set the default value for `code` on the `instance`.

    :param sender: The `LoremIpsum` class that sent the signal.
    :param instance: The `LoremIpsum` instance that is being
        initialised.
    :return: None.
    """
    if not instance.code:
        instance.code = "LOREM-{0.created:%Y%m%d-%H%M%S}".format(instance)
```

The `post_init` signal is sent by the class once it has done initialisation on the instance. This way, the instance gets a value for `code` before testing whether its non-nullable fields are set.